# file upload in Nodejs taking improper slashes\ and / in file path

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I have a nodejs server running ubunutu, and the application has a front end GUI to upload new files.

I accessed this application in chrome from windows - On selecting to  a new file and then submit getting below exception,the path is created with / and \ slashes

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/prj/app/tool/Node_js/app_new\bin\uploaded/upload_1fe04a100150431f7d11e9ccf54c58b2'

Now sure from where the path is being created taken as 'bin\uploaded/upload_1fe04a100150431f7d11e9ccf54c58b2'
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When joining parts of a path, use the `path.join()` function.

In your case, e.g.

```
path.join('/prj/app/tool/Node_js/app_new', 'bin\uploaded/upload_1fe04a100150431f7d11e9ccf54c58b2')
```

would result in

`/prj/app/tool/Node_js/app_new/bin/uploaded/upload_1fe04a100150431f7d11e9ccf54c58b2`

Comment: thank you, tried this but still facing the same error :(, not sure from which part of nodejs this path is created, any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Any packages you use in your app to handle the uploads? maybe posting the relevant dependencies would help.